# Get data by findAll and return two counts from another associated entity in the same request

Tags: mysql, node.js, mariadb, sequelize.js

I am using sequelize as an ORM. I need to fetch foos from DB along with 2 counts of bars (which Foo has many Bar. To be clear, i want the data to be like this notation for example:

```
{ fooId,fooTitle .., totalBarsCount, inprogressBarsCount }
```

I find a way that i can fetch one count using attributes.

I don't know if this is even possible in Sql.

Comment: Take a look at this article and see if it helps you: https://cmsdk.com/javascript/querying-in-include-with-attributes-for-count-in-sequelize.html

Comment: @FirminoChangani Cool, thank you